# Which layer should DBContext, Repository, and UnitOfWork be in?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, n-tier-architecture

I want to use Layered Architecture and EF, Repository and UoW Pattern in the project.

Which layer should DBContext, Repository, and UnitOfWork be in?

DAL or BLL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would put your DbContext implementation in your DAL (Data Access Layer). You will probably get different opinions on this, but I would not implement the repository or unit of work patterns. Technically, the DBContext is the unit of work and the IDbSet is a repository. By implementing your own, you are adding an abstraction on top of an abstraction.

More on this [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/47879/unit-of-work-and-repository-with-entity-framework-6) and [here](http://rob.conery.io/2014/03/04/repositories-and-unitofwork-are-not-a-good-idea/).

Comment: Most of the time I had an idea. Why does Microsoft ASP.Net offer to reveal this?

Answer (score 0):

DAL is an acronym for Data Access Layer. DbContext, repositories and Unit Of Work are related to working with data so you should definitely place them in DAL.

Answer (score 0):

"Should" is probably not the correct word here, as there are many views on this subject. 
If you want to implement these patterns out of the book, I would check out this link from the ASP.NET guys:
https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

But I actually have started to layer it like this:

Controller / Logic <- Where business logic and boundary objects are created and transformed.

Repository <- Where logic related to persistence and transforming entities and query objects

Store <- Where the actual implementations of storage mechanisms reside. This is abstracted away behind an interface.

This way leverages the fact that both the business logic and repository logic are testable, decoupled and free to use whatever mechanism for persistence - or lack thereof. Without the rest of the application knowing anything about it.

This is offcourse true with other patterns as well, this is just my take on this.

DbContext should never cross beyond the boundary of the DAL, if you want to put your repositories or units of work there, you are free to, just do not let them leak their details or dependencies upwards. The DbContext should in my opinion be scoped to as narrow scopes as possible, to keep it as clean as possible - you never know where that context has been... please wear protection! But jokes aside, if you have a async, multithreaded, multinode, big application, using these DbContexts everywhere passing them around, you will get into general concurrency and data race issues.

What I like to do is start with a InMemory store, that I inject into my controller. As soon as that store starts serving multiple entities, and the persistence logic get's more and more complex - I refactor it into a store with a repository on top. Once all my tests pass and I get it working like I want, I start to create database or file system based implementations of that store.

Again my opinions here, because this is a pretty general question, which has few "true" answers, just a lot of opinions.

Most opinions on this are valid, they just have different strengths and weaknesses, and the important part is to figure out which strengths you need, and how you will work with the weaknesses.

Answer (score 0):

Your repository should have a reference to `DbSet<T>` objects, and once you add, update or remove, from one or more repositories, you should invoke `SaveChanges` from the `UnitOfWork`. Therefore you should place `DbContext` into Unit of Work implementation.